# Python self, lists, and strings

Tags: python

I am very new to python coding. I stumbled upon this question and am currently confused. Why is there only a "self" attribute and how is it possible to return a list of strings?

```
def ridings_recorded(self) -> List[str]:
    """Return the ridings in which votes have been recorded in this
     election.

    >>> e = Election(date(2000, 2, 8))
    >>> e.update_results('r1', 'ndp', 1)
    >>> e.ridings_recorded()
    ['r1']
    >>> e.update_results('r2', 'ndp', 1)
    >>> e.ridings_recorded()
    ['r1', 'r2']
    """
```

How do I implement a function like this based on the given docstring?

Comment: self is usually used in a class to refer to elements in that class. you are able to return a list of strings because there are things inside of that class that is being updated such as with .update_results() and ridings_recorded() just returns that class variable.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

So, it's important to notice that the function `ridings_recorded` is a method in the Election class. All regular methods take `(self)` as the first parameter. Because the method takes no other parameters, it means that it requires no other input to run the method.

To better understand `(self)`, consider a method you may already know even if you are just starting to code- the `.pop()` method in lists. This method removes the last element from the list, as well as returns it. The `.pop()` method is a method of the class `list`. Here's a novice-friendly example that may help you understand it a bit more.

```py
>>> a = [1,2,3,4,5] #a is a list of numbers
>>> a  # this returns the list we just made
[1,2,3,4,5] 

>>> a.pop() #call the .pop() method on the list
5 #returns the last value in the list
>>> a
[1,2,3,4]  # as you see it also removes the last value in the list
```

Interestingly, `.pop()` method worked on the list `a`, even though we had no parameter input. However, if you were to read the code behind the class `list`, it would look something like this:

```
class list:
  ...
  ...
  def pop(self):
```

the `.pop()` method also takes in self as the parameter. Since you are using the method on an instance of the list class, you don't need to specify the parameter as Python knows that self is referring to the specific instance you called it on.

However, you could also call the `.pop()` method like this:

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> list.pop(a)  # call .pop() on the class and use the specific list instance as the parameter
5
>>> a
[1,2,3,4]
```

Because we called the method on the entire class, the `(self)` parameter was unspecified, so we had to explicitly write which instance in the `class list` we wanted to use the method on.

So in your specific case, `e` is in the `Election` class which has a method called `ridings_recorded`. It takes no parameters when called on an Election instance.

> How do I implement a function like this based on the given docstring?

You would create an Election instance with the parameters that it requires (check the `__init__`method). Then you would call it as shown in the docstring like `newvar.ridings_recorded()`

---

`-> List[str]` at the end designates the expected output type of the method/function. The method will return an error if for some reason a list of strings is not the final output; it also lets you know, as someone reading the code, what to expect very clearly.